# Is it possible to add same-site attribute to Spring Security CSRF's .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

My security configuration has a following line:

```
...csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())...
```

Which sends a csrf cookie with every request back to client. This cookie has no same-site attribute set. Is it possible to add the same-site attribute as well? I looked around some methods inside that class and there is nothing about extra attributes to my knowledge.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of version 4.0.1, the `servlet-api` doesn't allow you to add the `Same-Site` attribute to a `Cookie`. Hopefully this will change soon.

But in the meantime, you could provide your own `CsrfTokenRepository` implementation that instead of adding a `Cookie` to the `HttpServletResponse` (and thus being limited by the servlet-api's representation of a cookie), sets the cookie directly in HTTP header:

```
public class CustomCsrfTokenRepository implements CsrfTokenRepository {
    // implement other methods...

    @Override
    public void saveToken(CsrfToken token, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        // some version of this:
        response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly; SameSite=strict");
    }
}
```

You can take a look at [`CookieCsrfTokenRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CookieCsrfTokenRepository.java) to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring-Security 6.1 there is the method

`setCookieCustomizer(Consumer<ResponseCookie.ResponseCookieBuilder> cookieCustomizer)`

which allows to register a customizer like:

```
final CookieCsrfTokenRepository repo = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
repo.setCookieCustomizer((x) -> x.sameSite(Cookie.SameSite.NONE.attributeValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime in and follow NatFars answer, this solution is especially simple in Kotlin where you can delegate to other objects without having to copy code from the original object in hacky ways:

```
class CookieCsrfTokenRepositoryWrapper(private val repo: CsrfTokenRepository): CsrfTokenRepository by repo {

    override fun saveToken(token: CsrfToken?, req: HttpServletRequest?, res: HttpServletResponse?) {
        repo.saveToken(token, req, res)
        res?.getHeaders("Set-Cookie")?.toList()?.forEach {
            if(it.contains("XSRF") && !it.contains("SameSite"))
                res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "$it; SameSite=strict")
        }
    }
}

val repo = CookieCsrfTokenRepositoryWrapper(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
```

About delegation in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on user fast-reflexes in Java version for SameSite=Lax:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class CookieSameSiteLaxCsrfTokenRepository implements CsrfTokenRepository {

private static final String SET_COOKIE_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";
private static final String XSRF = "XSRF";
private static final String SAME_SITE = "SameSite";
private static final String SAME_SITE_LAX = "; SameSite=Lax";
private final CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository;

public static CookieSameSiteCsrfTokenRepository withHttpOnlyFalse() {
    return new CookieSameSiteCsrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}

@Override
public CsrfToken generateToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return cookieCsrfTokenRepository.generateToken(request);
}

@Override
public void saveToken(CsrfToken token, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    cookieCsrfTokenRepository.saveToken(token, request, response);

    CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(response.getHeaders(SET_COOKIE_HEADER))
            .forEach(header -> {
                if (header.contains(XSRF) && !header.contains(SAME_SITE)) {
                    response.setHeader(SET_COOKIE_HEADER, header + SAME_SITE_LAX);
                }
            });
}

@Override
public CsrfToken loadToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return cookieCsrfTokenRepository.loadToken(request);
}
}
```

In SecurityConfig in configure(HttpSecurity http):

```
http.
...
.and()
.csrf()
.csrfTokenRepository(CookieSameSiteLaxCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
```